# jquery mobile data-icon not appearing on a mobile device

Tags: css, mobile, jquery-mobile

I have a mobile web application (.NET MVC) and I'm using JQuery Mobile (beta 3 & jQuery 1.6.3).  My question is regarding the attribute 'data-icon' on various elements.  For example, I have an element:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext">Home</a>
```

When I run the application locally, everything appears as expected.  There is a small circular button with the 'home' image inside.  When I deploy my application to my host (Arvixe), this same button renders as expected in Chrome, but does not render as expected on my mobile phone (Nexus One).  On my phone, the home icon image does not appear at all.

JQuery mobile is referencing the image sprites in the following manner:

```
background-image:url(images/icons-18-white.png);
```

I can verify this image does in fact exist in the proper location, as it appears on the desktop browser, I can get to it with a URL (Desktop and Mobile) and my host log shows that requests to that URL are coming back with a 200 response.  I have even connected my web application, while hosted to a weinre server, and I can verify the DOM element does have the correct image path.  What's even stranger, is that when I go to jquerymobile.com on my phone, the same icons appear, the problem seems isolated to my hosted site.

Is there something I'm overlooking?  Thanks.

Comment: I don't see an issue with your code. have you hosted the image(s) on your server? or are you referencing the jQM hosted versions? try hosting them on your server if not?

Comment: Yes both the images and jquery/jquery mobile are both hosted on my server and I'm referencing them from there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I may have solved this.  When upgrading from jQuery mobile beta 2 to 3, I did not upgrade the corresponding images as well.  Grabbing the updated images seems to have done the trick.

Comment: Yep, I had the same problem, I only upgraded the JS and CSS and forgot the images folder. The weird thing was, the icons still appeared on iOS and desktop browsers! Just didn't work on Android.

Answer (score 3):

Plese place your images folder (which will come from jquery-mobile downloaded zip file) along with your css files.

Ex: If you have copied the .css files to some location named

```
d:\project\styles\jquery.mobile-1.x.x.css
```

Then please place the images folder as show below

```
d:\projects\styles\images
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set data-role="button" on anchors for them to appear as *buttons* with jQM (jQuery Mobile).
[see here](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/rzs8L/25/)

```
<a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext">Home</a>
```

this is the only thing I can think of.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that does not solve the issue.  It also isn't entirely true that all buttons need to be marked as 'data-role="button"'.  In this instance, the anchor is located within a header bar, per the example:  http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b3/docs/toolbars/docs-headers.html

Answer (score 0):

The latest jquerymobile has fixed this issue. If not, you need to check the following steps.

- check images folder of jquerymobile and jquerymobile CSS are in the same directory
- If you put jquerymobile CSS in separate folder, you need to change "path" in this stylesheet

Comment: By latest do you mean nightly build, or beta 3 (which I'm on)?  Please note from above, the images folder is in the same directory as the JQuery mobile CSS.